# Best Practice for Validating URLs

Tags: php

I have a form to get some urls from users. Eg: Web Address, Facebook Address, Twitter Address, Google+ address etc... My problem is how I validate these urls when they submit the form. I tried to validate URL in PHP by using the FILTER_VALIDATE_URL or simply, using regular expression.

Here, I would like to know what are the best methods to get such a urls from users. Is it always good to let them to enter protocol? sometimes they may not know it is http, https, ftp, ftps.. etc. I think it is something hard to do some users.

I tried something like this using FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, But it always use protocol and sometime I am confusing how its work..

```
// validate url
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

if (filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    echo "<br>valid";
} else {
    echo "<br>invalid";
}
```

OUTPUT : valid

```
// validate url
$url = 'hp://www.example.com';

if (filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    echo "<br>valid";
} else {
    echo "<br>invalid";
}
```

OUTPUT : valid

```
// validate url
$url = 'http://example.com';

if (filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    echo "<br>valid";
} else {
    echo "<br>invalid";
}
```

OUTPUT : valid

```
// validate url
$url = 'http://example.com?id=32&name=kamalani';

if (filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    echo "<br>valid";
} else {
    echo "<br>invalid";
}

OUTPUT : valid
```

Can you tell me what are the best ways to get urls from user and how those validate?

Any comments are greatly appreciating..

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried Regex ? good Regex can serve the purpose. never invent on your own, when you have some thing already in your bag :)  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: asking protocol from user it good or bad?

Comment: it's not about asking bad or good.  there are many threads already there in SO.  but as of now question fits in Not a real question category or even it might not be helpful to others. as i said above just use Regex. will do the trick for you. for best practices you may post a question in programmers.stackechange.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expression to check valid url here.

Please try this :

```
  $pattern = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
  $URL= 'http://example.com?id=32&name=kamalani';

  if(preg_match($pattern, $URL) ){
    echo "<br>valid";
  } else{
  echo "<br>invalid";
  }
```

**Output**

```
 valid
```

Comment: Assume user given like this url.. Eg: www.example.com then what happen

Comment: www.example.com is valid or not?

Comment: www.example.com is valid url as per my example